# Allow Login using Username or Email and password in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC. I want to create Text-box username or email based on 
    that user entered. I need to check with a database. How can I achieve that?

Login View

```
  @Html.TextboxFor(d=>d.username,new{@class="form-control"})

  @Html.TextboxFor(d=>d.password,new{@class="form-control"})
```

Model class

```
public string username {get;set;}
public string password {get;set;}
public string Email {get;set;}
```

I don't want to create another Field for Email.
During login check, I want to check username/email both, if any of them is true, then allow a respective user to log in.

Comment: @shyamy Do you want to add the same textbox for username/email that checks valid username or email for the user login? Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: @shyamy you can use ASP.NET Identity --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: you can use Custom Data Annotation Validation. it is perfect for your case

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by too many ways. You can also use asp.net membership.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/using-membership-in-Asp-Net-mvc-4/

When you are verifying valid user on "Login" button click, just need to check the username and email both.

Comment: in the textbox, if they enter a username or email  it should check if it is a username or email then proceed to the login,  this is my requirement

Comment: Yes, You can do that in backend at the time when you are checking valid user. You just need to check the username and email both. If any of the value is valid, then the user is valid. Your model class will not have separate class property for the email field.

Comment: is that good way to check in the controller the entered value is Email or username?

Comment: Yes, you can make a DB call from the controller. Your SQL query will check the username and email both with a combination of a password. "SELECT TOP 1 FROM [tablename] WHERE (stUsername = @username OR stEmail = @username) AND stPassword = @Password"

Comment: Please mark it as a answer If it is useful to you or upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow simple steps:
1) Name this view as Login.cshtml

> > @model YourNameSpace.Models.Login
> >
> > @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Sample", FormMethod.Post, 
> >                                           new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))  {
> >         @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
> >
> > ```
> >    @Html.TextboxFor(d=>d.username,new{@class="form-control"})
> >
> >    @Html.TextboxFor(d=>d.password,new{@class="form-control"})
> > ```
>
> }

2) And in your Index Action of Sample Controller:

> ```
>      [HttpPost]
>     public ActionResult Index(Login login)
>
>     {
>         if (ModelState.IsValid)
>         {
>             string con = "YOUR CONNECTION STRING";
>             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Users where username=@username and password=@password ", con);
>             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", login.Username);
>             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", login.Password);
>
>             con.Open();
>
>             SqlDataReader dr = default(SqlDataReader);
>
>             dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
>
>             while ((dr.Read()) == true)
>             {
>                 lbluser.Text = dr["UserName"].ToString();
>                 lblpwd.Text = dr["password"].ToString();
>             }
>
>             dr.Close();
>
>             con.Close();
>         }
>         return RedirectToAction("Index");
>     }
> ```

Please make sure **con** is the connection string that points to the database and Users is your table.